# New gfci outlet keeps tripping

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, smart-switch

I installed a new gfci outlet outside through my attic to power a roof de-icer cable.
I tapped into a dedicated outlet for an air conditioner that runs to the floor below.
Additionally in the attic I installed a smart switch for the new gfci outlet.
Initially everything was working fine but the gfci outlet keeps tripping. There is nothing plugged into the original outlet and the switch was off but when I checked this morning the gfci tripped.
What would be the best way to troubleshoot this?

I used one of these outdoor covers - https://a.co/d/2vg7f5s.  However there is an opening where the plug runs out so there is a chance for moisture.   I’m sure it is not overloaded as nothing else is plugged into the circuit.

I just realized that this is a 15 amp circuit ans I used a 20 amp gfci outlet.  Could that be this cause the outlet to trip?

Comment: Being outside it could just be moisture in the GFCI.  Usually recommended that GFCIs be inside and just have a regular outlet be protected with the GFCI.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!   I used one of these outdoor covers - https://a.co/d/2vg7f5s.  However there is an opening where the plug runs out.   I’m sure it is not overloaded as nothing else is plugged into the circuit.  
Could this be a wiring issue?

Comment: Cannot rule out a wiring issue.  GFCIs do not trip on a overload(that is the breakers job).  They do trip when they find some current on ground, but if bad wires or just moisture creating a path is hard to tell unless you can make sure the insides are dry.

Comment: Does the smart switch connect to hot/neutral/ground? Or just hot and ground? Some smart switches cheat by leaking current through ground, which would rightfully trip the GFCI if it's attached to the load terminals.

Comment: When you say "tapped in" do you mean that you cut the cable, and put the junction box inline, with some wires going "in" and other wires going "out"?  When you did that, did you use the LOAD terminals on the GFCI?  (mistake).  Also super important, are you sure this is a 120V air conditioner and not 240V?

Comment: The smart switch connects to hot ,neutral and ground.   
I “tapped in” by cutting the wire and adding a junction  box.   
The AC was 120v.    
I will check that I properly wired the GFCI.   If I used the load terminal would this cause it to trip or not work at all?